# Ruby: How to display charts from Google Analytics?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-analytics

Is there a gem or way to display charts from Google Analytics? I want to make charts with visitors and page views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Garb](https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb) is a ruby library for Google Analytics, that will help you get the numerical data.

Once you have the data, you can use the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) to graph it in a bunch of different ways.

Google Chart API Ruby lib: [googlecharts](https://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts)

Comment: I tried to use Google Chart API on another task and it wasn't as nice and flexible as I needed it to be. I recommend the Google Visualisation API, which seems to be exactly what they used to generate the graphs displayed inside Google Analytics to generate Flash charts. Another nice option which is not dependent on remote servers to generate the graphs is Highcharts, a JavaScript charting library, which seems to be quite mature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the documentation? http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts.html shows example approaches of using google analytics data.